# org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException

Tags: java, groovy, ssh

I have an exception then code tries execute the line  "execute 'sudo systemctl stop roc && systemctl start roc' "

Caused by: org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException: Command returned exit status 1: sudo systemctl stop roc && systemctl start roc

```
remotes {
    webServer {
    host = '192.168.0.1'
    user = 'vasid'
    password = 'XXXX'
}
}

task deploy {
    doLast {
        ssh.run {
            session(remotes.webServer) {
                put from: '/work/roc.jar',
                        into: '/opt/roc'
                execute 'sudo systemctl stop roc &&        systemctl start roc'
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: and maybe you just forgot to use `sudo` for `systemctl start roc`